# How to alter a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

In a chain for promises is there any way to have one of the members add promises to the chain?

This code illustrates better what I mean:

```
$.ajax(......).then(function(r){

  .....
  return r;

}).then(function(r){

  var d = $.Deferred();
  // how to add d.promise() to this chain ?
  ....
  return r;

}).then(function(r){

  // this function should be able to receive "r"
  // but should also wait for the promise above to complete :(

  ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have too much experience with jQuery promises but definitely you can pay a promise with another one, just like [Nicolas Bevacqua](https://twitter.com/nzgb) explain it in this Ponyfoo article [ES6 Promises in Depth](http://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-promises-in-depth#paying-a-promise-with-another-promise).

```
var p = Promise.resolve()
  .then(data => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(Math.random() > 0.5 ? resolve : reject, 1000)
  }))

p.then(data => console.log('okay!'))
p.catch(data => console.log('boo!'))
```

I hope you can adapt it to your needs or maybe use the native promises instead.

Answer (score 1):

To return `r` from `.then()` , use `.resolve()` with argument `r` within `$.Deferred()` `beforeStart` function , return `d.promise()` from `.then()` for `r` to be accessible at next `.then()` in chain

```
 .then(function(r) {

  .....
    var d = $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
      // do stuff
      dfd.resolve(r)
    });
    // how to add d.promise() to this chain ?
    ....
    return d.promise();
 })
```

```js
$.when(1).then(function(r) {
  return r;
}).then(function(r) {

  var d = $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(function() {
      dfd.resolve(r)
    }, Math.random() * 2500)
  });
  // how to add d.promise() to this chain ?
  //....
  return d.promise();
})
.then(function(r) {
  console.log(r)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Returning the promise from within the `.then()` handler is how you link newly created promises.  This looks like the right answer to me.

Comment: Note you can just `return d` since in jQuery a deferred is also a promise with a `then`.